# Remove duplicates based on one column in each group

Tags: mysql

I have db that looks like this: `RoomRegistrations 1 <--> 1 Students 1 <--> 1 BorrowedBooks`

```
RoomRegistrations:
RoomId | Id
1      | 92051048757
1      | 92342103461
2      | 92430234763

Students:
Id          | Name  | Surname
92051048757 | Tom   | Jones
92342103461 | Andrew| Brown
92430234763 | Brad  | Morrison

BorrowedBooks:
BookId | Id          | Title
1      | 92051048757 | Abcdefg
2      | 92342103461 | Abcdefg
3      | 92430234763 | hijklmn
```

Basically each student can borrow any number of books they want, but there's one restriction. There cannot be duplicate books in any room, so if Student A borrows Abcd and Student B borrows Abcd and they both live in room 1 then I want to select only one copy and ignore duplicates in that room.

For me there's a lot going on and I don't know how to tackle this. I know that I need to group students by `RoomId`, so I get groups:

```
SELECT RoomRegistrations.RoomId, Students.Name, Students.Surname, BorrowedBooks.Title
FROM (RoomRegistrations INNER JOIN Students ON RoomRegistrations.Id = Students.Id) 
INNER JOIN BorrowedBooks 
ON Students.Id = BorrowedBooks.Id
GROUP BY RoomRegistrations.RoomId, Students.Name, Students.Surname, BorrowedBooks.Title;
```

Now I need to filter each group by only one column which is `Title` so that I get rid of duplicates in each group in field `Title`, and this is where I'm stuck.

Comment: You should before decide if you want or not show Students.Name and Surname and which one (you got two Surname for one room...)

Comment: It's not important which one from a room I choose, so the first one that is returned is fine.

Comment: The sample data provided do not seem to contain any duplicates

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query in order to pick *just one* student id *for each* existent `RoomId` - `BookId`:

```
SELECT rr.RoomId, bb.BookId, MIN(s.Id)
FROM RoomRegistrations AS rr
JOIN Students AS s ON rr.Id = s.Id
JOIN BorrowedBooks AS bb ON s.Id = bb.Id
GROUP By rr.RoomId, bb.BookId;
```

The query just picks the student having the minimum `Id` value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with only one between `Name` and `Surname`, you could achieve that just using `max()` to that column

```
SELECT  t1.RoomId, max(t2.Surname), t3.Title
FROM    RoomRegistrations t1
JOIN    Students t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id) 
JOIN    BorrowedBooks t3
ON      t2.Id = t3.Id
GROUP BY t1.RoomId, t3.Title
```

If you want both this cannot work, because `max(Name)` and `max(Surname)` could belong to different students. In this case, you can add one more `join` with a table that gets you the first `Surname` (or `Name`, whatever you prefer)

```
SELECT  t1.RoomId, t2.Name, t2.Surname, t3.Title
FROM    RoomRegistrations t1
JOIN    Students t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id) 
JOIN    BorrowedBooks t3
ON      t2.Id = t3.Id
JOIN    (
            select  t1.RoomId, t3.Title, max(t2.Surname) Surname
            FROM    RoomRegistrations t1
            JOIN    Students t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id) 
            JOIN    BorrowedBooks t3
            ON      t2.Id = t3.Id
            GROUP BY t1.RoomId, t3.Title
        ) t4
ON      t1.RoomId = t4.RoomId and t3.Title = t4.Title and t2.Surname = t4.Surname
GROUP BY t1.RoomId, t2.Name, t2.Surname, t3.Title
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
CREATE TABLE RR (ROOMID int, ID BIGINT);
INSERT INTO RR VALUES (1,92051048757);
INSERT INTO RR VALUES (1,92342103461);

CREATE TABLE S (ID BIGINT, NAME VARCHAR(20), SURNAME VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO S VALUES (92051048757 ,'Tom','Jones');
INSERT INTO S VALUES (92342103461  ,'And','Brown');
INSERT INTO S VALUES (92430234763  ,'Brad','Morr');

 CREATE TABLE BB (BOOKID INT, ID BIGINT, TITLE VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO BB VALUES (1, 92051048757  ,'abcd');
INSERT INTO BB VALUES (2, 92342103461   ,'abcd');
INSERT INTO BB VALUES (3, 92430234763   ,'hjik');

SELECT X.* , S.NAME, S.SURNAME
FROM (
    SELECT RR.RoomId,  BB.Title, MIN(RR.ID) AS STUD_ID 
    FROM RR 
    INNER JOIN S ON RR.Id = S.Id
    INNER JOIN BB ON S.Id = BB.Id
    GROUP BY RR.RoomId, BB.Title
    ) X
INNER JOIN S ON X.STUD_ID=S.ID
;
```

Output:

```
    RoomId  Title   STUD_ID NAME    SURNAME
1   1   abcd    92051048757 Tom Jones
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant post this as a comment because my reputation is not high enough but I wanted to add to what Stefano sugested, you can choose name and surname using a concat statement:

```
mysql> select rooms.rID, 
       max(concat(students.name," ",students.surname)) as name, 
       books.title from ( rooms join students on rooms.sID = students.sID ) 
       join books on books.sID = students.sID 
       group by rooms.rID,books.title;

+-----+---------------+---------+
| rID | name          | title   |
+-----+---------------+---------+
|   1 | Tom Jones     | Abcdefg |
|   2 | Brad Morrison | Hijklm  |
+-----+---------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```